# Why is my simple rewrite code causing a redirect loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me make this work.

I'm trying to make `domain.com/painting.php?name=hello` redirect to `domain.com/page/hello` while keeping my rewrite :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]+) 
RewriteRule ^painting\.php$ /page/%1? [R=301,L] #redirects to page
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ painting.php?name=$1 [L] #rewrites painting
```

I would like to keep only the "pretty url". Please help.

Found answer here: [simple 301 redirect with variable not working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7812059/922791)

Comment: because you redirect painting to page and later page to painting?

Comment: What happens if you swap the second and third lines? Also, try adding the QSA flag to the first line, so [QSA,L]

Comment: I'm with @JoLoCo - I think your rewriting it to something gets rewritten.  Swap them and see what happens.

Comment: What's with everyone getting URL rewriting ass-backwards lately? The objective is to rewrite a readable URL like `page/hello` to a less-friendly but usable one like `painting.php?name=hello` not *redirect* the latter to the former

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you actually want to do is be able to accept the URL `domain.com/page/hello` and rewrite it (invisibly) to `domain.com/painting.php?name=hello`. If so, try this

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/.])+/?$ painting.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks for putting it into words for me :) unfortunately I get a 500 internal error with this code

Comment: @checkenginelight Oops, typo (missing `)`). Fixed now