# Remove .php extension (explicitly written) for friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

htaccess to remove the .php extension of my site's files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Now, if I go to my site

```
www.mysite.com/home
```

works fine, it redirects to home.php but the URL is still friendly.

But if I write this URL:

```
www.mysite.com/home.php
```

The home.php is served, and the URL is not friendly.

How can I avoid this behavior? I want that if the user writes www.mysite.com/home.php, the URL displayed in the URL bar be www.mysite.com/home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can remove .php from requests like so

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That part of the problem works. My main problem is that if the user introduces mysite.com/file.php, I want the URL to be rewritten to mysite.com/file

Comment: yes, the above will redirect `mysite.com/file.php` to `mysite.com/file` - then be aware of infinite loops - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823801/remove-php-extention-stop-access-of-url-with-php-extention-and-remove-trailing

Comment: Thanks @scibuff. But is it possible to change the browser's URL? I still cannot get it modified.

Comment: use `[L,R=301]` instead of `[L,QSA]`

Comment: Argh! Now I'm getting the `310 error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`
I've commented this line `#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f`
and changed the `QSA`to `R=301`
Is this so difficult to get it work? I think that I'll have to use  the solution provided by @Artjom Kurapov

Comment: yes, you're almost there, read the link i posted above on how to avoid infinite loops

Comment: Thanks @scibuff. But I don't want my "friendly url" to have the "extra" no-redirect-loop URL parameter,as I want friendly URL for SEO.

Answer (score 10):

Code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]


# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: Spent hours trying so many solutions, yours works and is well commented. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can also put this code inside of your `.htaccess` file:

```
options +multiviews
```

What this does is to search for available extensions (.html, .htm and .php I think) inside the current directory. So if for example you request `/user` it will look for `user.php`.

Comment: Your answer is definitely the best one for what he wants :)

Comment: Humm, maybe not. If I put /user, then all it's ok, it redirects to /user.php. But if I put /user.php, I want the browser's URL be changed to /user also, and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You could add a `htaccess` rule to redirect all `*.php` to `*` like so: `rewriterule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [r=301,l]`. (I cannot test it right at the moment, but it should work).

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite is ignored because it checks for existing file, based on your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

I would suggest adding a URL check in php to redirect to itself (without extension). Or do you want to display 404 error if someone access existing file?

Comment: If I remove that RewriteCond, what will be the effect? I don't see any difference. Is there a proper way to do it with .htaccess, instead of redirecting in php?

Comment: it will be routing all traffic to your file.. but since I doubt that you'll have something like home.php.php , it will result in 404. Well apache cant say to the browser to change URL in navigation to something cleaner. Mod rewrite just transforms one URL requests to others.. SO you have to state what logic you want - redirect or still serve the page.. or 404