# Removing .php from url - Only rewriting child pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to remove the .php extensions from a site, which I have gotten to work.  `example.com/parent/child.php` correctly changes to `example.com/parent/child/`

However, when going to `example.com/parent.php` it still rewrites properly but shows an index page.

I'm fairly new to `.htaccess` and Apache, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update from the comments**

"My apologies, Its not letting me write the code. I grabbed it from this post:

[Remove .php extension (explicitly written) for friendly URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url)"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]


# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: Well, there is nothing we can do if you don't post your rewriting rules...

Comment: My apologies, Its not letting me write the code.  I grabbed it from this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url

The post from Bhavana.

Comment: Did you copy and paste more than one code?

Comment: No I just used the code as shown above.