# Remove php extension from url

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have url `example.com/lt.php/example` and want remove .php that will be `example.com/lt/example`
 I try with htacces, but I think that's impossible

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://moliplante.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: i think there is a similar question on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php/(.+)$ $1/$2
```

The first backreference would capture lt from lt.php and the second backreference would have example and php would be added to it.

Comment: i made an edit...it just appended .php to the end of the second backreference

Comment: @TomasLietuva This does work. If you need it to redirect, just add the `[R]` flag. If you want `example.com/lt/example` to actually execute `example.com/lt.php/example` internally (or probably more something like `example.com/lt.php?key=example`) then you should add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will work

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```