# How to keep file extension removed in address bar?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I am using following code to remove `.php` extension from URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

My question is how to keep it removed just like stack overflow does. If my URL is `domain.com/about.php` it is redirected to `domain.com/about` but if someone types `.php` after `about` intentionally it remains there. Also, if someone directly visits `domain.com/about.php` it still remains there. How can I remove any extensions from URL just like stackoverflow does even if user types it intentionally? If this can't be done in `.htacess` can I do it in JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: if you are using codeigniter, it will never give .php as all views is called from controller's side(MVC pattern), so you can give your controller and view name same...

Comment: The term you're looking for is, "routing"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension (explicitly written) for friendly URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This will redirect

```
http://example.com/file.php
```

to

```
http://example.com/file
```

and then rewrite :

```
http://example.com/file
```

to

```
http://example.com/file.php
```

Comment: Thanks. However, If it is redirecting `.php` to `not php` and then rewriting it to `.php` then what purpose does it serve? I want to keep the extension removed.

Comment: This remove the .php extension completly, meaning that if you type http://example.com/file.php you will be redirected to  http://example.com/file

Comment: @Strakeen Could you please explain what each line does? This will help  me to write my own `.htaccess` next time. If not that could you provide URl of some resourse which I can read to know more about how these `.htaccess` statements work?

Answer (score 0):

> **Magic Rewrites for Clean URLs when using Apache Web Server:**

This process consists of a few steps. You should feel like a ninja for wanting to do this and put in the extra effort. It's worth it!

> **Place a .htaccess file in the folder you're working in:** (for example, if you're working in directory `/company/` you'd put this in `/company/.htaccess`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

So, we've now got a path on your server that will accept anything inside of it, if it doesn't exist. For example, if you point to `/company/Joe_Plumber` it will redirect to index.php. If you point to `/company/style.css` and it exists and has correct permissions, it'll give you the file you asked for.

> **Create an index.php file in that directory.** (for example, `/company/index.php`)

Now, inside your .php file you're going to have to process what the user asked for. Basename will give you only the last folder, so if we requested `/company/foo/bar` it will only get `bar`

```
$q = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$q = str_replace('_',' ',$q); // Convert any underscores to spaces
echo "Hi, {$q}!";
```

That's all there is to it. If there is any way I can clarify or help, just ask.