# completely remove the .php extension from url

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The last few days, I've really been messing with the `.php` extension. I used mod_rewrite (via `.htaccess`) to redirect from `www.example.com/example.php` to `www.exmaple.com/example` and it works fine.
But I found out that I could still enter the url `www.example.com/example.php` to visit the page rather than show a not found page. How could I do that?

This is what I mean:
If you try to entered the first link before, it will work fine but the second link is the Forum page from phpacademy it will redirect to a error page. But my page will still work fine too. I want the effect like this.
Forum page without .php extension
Forum page with .php extension

Much appreciate any help

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823801/remove-php-extention-stop-access-of-url-with-php-extention-and-remove-trailing | http://stackoverflow.com/a/7823959/689579

Answer (score 1):

You could have following as .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```